# add 'a jar file and its dependencies' to final .Zip via Maven Assembly Plugin

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-assembly-plugin

I want to make a .Zip file by Maven Assembly Plugin and put these files into it:

1. executable jar
2. related classes in lib folder
3. a script to run that jar
4. a folder that contains some other dependencies (like lib folder) and other classes(jars) that are needed because of these dependencies!

   and my question is about number 4: is there any way to put these dependencies automatically?

thanks ..

Comment: in other word, is there any way to find out dependency of a jar (module)  without having its pom.xml ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maven assembly website has the folowing examples which I think, answer most of your questions : http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/examples/single/index.html

Comment: thanks Denis, I took a look at this link. but my problem still exist!

Comment: This link may be a good pointer, but is not a complete answer. Would be great if a relevant example was included here.